# Not able to link SFML libraries with Cmake to C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, c++17, sfml

I've been trying to compile SFML libraries on Visual studio using Cmake project. I've downloaded VCPKG and extracted SFML 64bit version of it (both bin and lib files) in my working directory (Dijakstra2). Then I tried to link libraries through cmake and when I'm trying to generate cmakelists.txt it gives an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
--->Error       CMake Error at Dijakstra2/CMakeLists.txt:15 (set_property):
  set_property not given a PROPERTY <name> argument.        C:\Users\narek\source\repos\Dijakstra2\Dijakstra2/CMakeLists.txt    15
```

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Dijakstra2, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (Dijakstra2 "Dijakstra2.cpp" "Dijakstra2.h")
target_link_libraries(Dijakstra2 $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/library/sfml-graphics.lib)
target_link_libraries(Dijakstra2 $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/library/sfml-audio.lib)
target_link_libraries(Dijakstra2 $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/library/sfml-system.lib)
target_link_libraries(Dijakstra2 $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/library/sfml-window.lib)

include_directories ($(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/include)
set_property (TARGET Dijakstra2 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set_property (TARGET Dijakstra2 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory? Your second `set_property` needs a `PROPERTY` the same as your first one

Comment: @AlanBirtles Well this is the first time I'm using cmake, and it's a bit overwhelming. Based on an online tutorial they used the exact code and SFML successfully linked to VS.  Now how I can try to set the second property here? :      set_property (TARGET Dijakstra2 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

Comment: `set_property (TARGET Dijakstra2 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles now it gives another error on cmake (about VCPKG probably) ......
Error  CMake Error:
  Running

   'C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe' '-C' 'C:/Users/narek/source/repos/Dijakstra2/out/build/x64-Debug' '-t' 'recompact'

  failed with:

   ninja: error: build.ninja:82: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)
    INCLUDES = -IC:\Users\narek\source\repos\Dijakstra2\Dijakstra2\$(CMAKE...

Comment: Cmake variables use `{` not `(`

Comment: @Nar: Please note, that while everyone sometime makes a typo in the code, Stack Overflow is NOT the site for "find a typo in my code". We expect that at the time a question is posted, the asker has already performed basic checks for the posted code.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks a lot! Sorry if my questions sound silly. This is my first time that I have to work with Cmake, and I'm totally a beginner in it.  I'm pretty sure that was the entire problem. Thanks again